# Rails 6 Trix editor not styled properly / not functioning properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, trix

[image: Trix Editor on my Heroku staging environment]

I'm not sure why the trix editor is displaying incorrectly on my Heroku staging environment.
Locally it displays as you would expect from Trix. I've checked the yarn installations in my staging env and afaik there are no issues with those. I've been scratching my head with this for about 2 hours now.

Comment: have you check on the js console? maybe there is CSS error
or you haven't load its CSS

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I had to import it in the `packs/application.js` file